# Why does the Baum- Welch converge?

Tags: statistics, stochastic-processes

I have just studied hidden Markov models and I wonder that if the Baum- Welch algorithm converges. Does anyone explain to me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Briefly, it's an EM algorithm for the specific likelihood given by an HMM. [This](http://cs229.stanford.edu/notes/cs229-notes8.pdf) set of notes explains it nicely.